# write a text on images with a php function

Tags: javascript, php

I want to write a text(say "my text" ) on an image using PHP5.

I am using this

```
 $src = imagecreatefromjpeg($path);
 $temp = imagecreatetruecolor($newwidth, $newheight);
 $black = imagecolorallocatealpha($temp,0,0,16,75);
  $start_x = 10;
  $start_y = 20;
    putenv('GDFONTPATH=' . realpath('.'));

     $font = "LongCoolWoman";
      $black = ImageColorAllocate($src, 255, 255, 255);
      imagecopyresampled($temp, $src, 0,0,0,0, $newwidth, $newheight, $width, $height);
      Imagettftext($src, 12, 0, $start_x, $start_y, $black, $font , "my text");
                                                       imagejpeg($temp, $path,100);
                                                       imagedestroy($temp);
```

i am having this error

```
error `imagettftext(): Could not find/open font in ...`
```

font file (LongCoolWoman ) and my php file are in the same folder.

Comment: Either the font (TTF file) is not in the proper place or the name of the font doesn't match the name within the TTF file itself.  I've had a number of fonts show as one name in Word or Excel only to have a different name when used elsewhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the value in $font does not end with '.ttf' PHP will automatically append .ttf and search for the font in the servers font librarys. You should set the $font as follows.

```
$font = './LongCoolWoman.ttf'
```

This way the font file should be found in your current folder alongside your script.

Comment: You also may want to put a full path to the font file incase the relative path dosnt work for any reason.

Comment: thanks Dan now there's no error , but there is also no text om image , it could the color of my text do you see anything incorrect that my causes this problem?

Comment: I think 255,255,255 would produce white. You want to use 0,0,0 to create black. `$black = imagecolorallocate($src, 0, 0, 0);`